# Como obtener un dato de MySQL y utilizarlo?

Tags: mysql, android

Estoy trabajando un proyecto en Android Studio, y necesito realizar un calculo de consumo de un servicio de la siguiente forma:

Nombre: XXXX
Apellido: XXXXX
Lectura de servicio: XXX
Consumo:    <---- Aqui necesito que se muestre el calculo

La información está almacenada en una base de datos, segun el campo de  lectura necesito que se realice dicho calculo.

Como obtengo ese dato de consumo realizando un procedimiento de resta con el campo de lectura?

```
public class Formulario extends AppCompatActivity implements 
Response.Listener<JSONObject> ,Response.ErrorListener{

EditText Cod, Cuenta, Nombre, Lect;
Button btnagregar;
RequestQueue request;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_formulario);

    Cod= findViewById(R.id.contador);
    Cuenta=findViewById(R.id.nocuenta);
    Nombre=findViewById(R.id.nombrecliente);
    Lect=findViewById(R.id.lectura);
    btnagregar=findViewById(R.id.registrarform);
    request= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    btnagregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           insertar();
       }
   });

}
JsonRequest jrq;


public void insertar(){
    String url= "http://192.168.1.72/tesis/insertar2.php?codcontador="+Cod.getText()+"&cuentacontador="+Cuenta.getText()+"&nombrecontador="+Nombre.getText()+"&lecturacontador="+Lect.getText()+"";

   jrq=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,  null, this, this);
    request.add (jrq);
```

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando para poder llenar mi formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la imagen del layout

En el campo consumo, deseo realizar el calculo de lo que registré en el campo de lectura menos la lectura anterior y multiplicado por un valor 
  (lectura actual - lectura anterior)(7.14)

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a **StackOverflow**, Que has intentado ? sube el código que has intentado, en la comunidad no es bien recibido las preguntas tipo "Necesito hacer esto" y no evidenciar al menos un poco de investigación de tu parte, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código, para que no recibas puntaje negativo y realiza el https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Muestra el código donde agregas los valores a los EditText @chris_gt

Comment: Para esto tienes que implementar una petición al servidor, para pedirle los datos vía la URL. Generalmente esto se hace con `Volley` o con `AsyncTask`. Aquí mismo hay varios ejemplos, sobre todo con `Volley`, que sería lo más recomendable. Del lado del servidor, por lo general devuelves un JSON con la respuesta, que luego recibes en Android para leerlo y mostrar los datos.